# Use different markers in the same series of an irregular time highchart

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to display an irregular time series in highcharts that also has different markers for each point.  I can find no example of how this combination of data should be formatted.

Irregular time series point:
***[Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 40],***

Different Markers each point:
***{y: 40, marker: {symbol: 'url(http://myurl.com/image.png)' }},***

I have tried to combine these in several ways, but have not come up with the proper way. This is the best I have come up with. It still does not display, but does not completely kill the chart either.  Is there a way to combine these?
**[Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), {y: 40, marker: {symbol: 'url(http://myurl.com/image.png)' }}],**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there!

You have to separate out the date and the value into `x` and `y`. What you're looking for should be something like this:

```
{
    x: Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18),
    y: 0.7,
    marker: {
        symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
    }
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle showing the concept: http://jsfiddle.net/mkremer90/KrcQx/

Comment: Sounds good, if this worked out for you be sure to choose it as the answer and upvote. =) Glad I could help!

Comment: Can select the answer, but not able to upvote as I have no rep